# Using Processing-3.2.2 from shell

Tags: shell, audio, video, terminal, processing

guys, I am working on audio visualization and made a successful running file in pde. The code takes an "input.mp3" then export the .mp4 file. Can it be possible that we can use it through the terminal(.sh)? I mean with writing some command it executes the program. like:

```
processing-3.2.2 filename.pde input.mp3
```

And it produces the video of that input.mp3. Here's my code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import com.hamoid.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;
AudioMetaData meta;
BeatDetect beat;
VideoExport videoExport;
int  r = 200;
float rad = 70;
void setup()
{
  size(600, 600);
  //size(600, 400);
  minim = new Minim(this);
  player = minim.loadFile("son_final.mp3");
  meta = player.getMetaData();
  beat = new BeatDetect();
  videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "basic.mp4");
  player.loop();
  //player.play();
  background(-1);
  noCursor();
}

void draw()
{ 
  float t = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 1);
  beat.detect(player.mix);
  fill(#1A1F18, 20);
  noStroke();
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  noFill();
  fill(-1, 10);
  if (beat.isOnset()) rad = rad*0.9;
  else rad = 70;
  ellipse(0, 0, 2*rad, 2*rad);
  stroke(-1, 50);
  int bsize = player.bufferSize();
  for (int i = 0; i < bsize - 1; i+=5)
  {
    float x = (r)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y = (r)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float x2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    line(x, y, x2, y2);
  }
  beginShape();
  noFill();
  stroke(-1, 50);
  for (int i = 0; i < bsize; i+=30)
  {
    float x2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*cos(i*2*PI/bsize);
    float y2 = (r + player.left.get(i)*100)*sin(i*2*PI/bsize);
    vertex(x2, y2);
    pushStyle();
    stroke(-1);
    strokeWeight(2);
    point(x2, y2);
    popStyle();
  }
  endShape();
   if (flag) showMeta();
   videoExport.saveFrame();
 }



void showMeta() {
  int time =  meta.length();
  textSize(50);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text( (int)(time/1000-millis()/1000)/60 + ":"+ (time/1000-millis()/1000)%60, -7, 21);
}

boolean flag =false;
void mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, width/2, height/2)<150) flag =!flag;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key==' ')exit();
  if(key=='s')saveFrame("###.jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a `.pde` file from the command line or from a script.

But you can convert the `.pde` file into a Java application, and then run that Java application just like you'd run any other Java application.

As a first step, from your Processing editor, go to `File > Export Application...` which brings up the Export Options window. Set your options there (might play around a bit to see what each option does) and then click the `Export` button.

That will export the application to your sketch directory. That application gives you various `.java` and `.jar` files that you can use as a Java application.

From there it's just a matter of running the `.jar` files exactly like you'd run any other `.jar` file.

Comment: Hey @KevinWorkman I tried that export option and it does export the files. But I am getting too many files. How can I know which file to run in the script?

Comment: @PradhvanBisht You need all of the files. You'd run the `.jar` or `.java` file that has the name of your sketch, and you'd add the rest to your classpath. From a script that's the `-cp` option.